# Conditions for multivariable differentiability

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

For a nonlinear system of equations: $x' = f(x)$ why is it that the following condition is equivalent to being differentiable at $x_0$.

Condition:
\begin{equation}
f(x) = A(x-x_0) + g(x)
\end{equation}

where $A$ is an $n x n$ constant matrix and $g$ satisfies:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to x_0} \dfrac{||g(x)||}{||x-x_0||} = 0
\end{equation}

Maybe I am confused because I do not understand the term differentiable for a multivariable equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Differentiable" in a multivariable context means the same thing as it does in a single-variable context: namely, that the function can, locally, be accurately approximated by a linear function.

In this case, the linear function is $x\mapsto A(x-x_0)$; the $g(x)$ is simply the error in that approximation; and the condition
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{\|g(x)\|}{\|x-x_0\|}=0
$$
just means that the error in the linear approximation goes to 0 "fast enough".